# iOS 11 drag and drop support for UIViewcontroller with UITableView

Tags: ios, ios11

Is drag and drop support available *only* to `UITableViewController`? Updating the sample app provided by Apple to `UIViewController` containing a `UITableView`, drops stop working. [Here is what it looks like.](https://youtu.be/7sY3KWog9D4)

Am I missing something here? Has anyone got this working with a plain `UIViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

i've done drag and drop with image in *UIViewController*

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIDropInteractionDelegate,UIDragInteractionDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    view.addInteraction(UIDropInteraction(delegate: self))
    view.addInteraction(UIDragInteraction(delegate: self))

}
//MARK:-  drop item
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {
    for dragItem in session.items{
        dragItem.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self, completionHandler: { (obj, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to load",err)
                return
            }
            guard let draggedImage = obj as? UIImage else {
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let imageView = UIImageView(image: draggedImage)
                imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                self.view.addSubview(imageView)
                imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: draggedImage.size.width, height: draggedImage.size.height)
                let centerPoint = session.location(in: self.view)
                imageView.center = centerPoint
            }


        })
    }
}
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
    return session.canLoadObjects(ofClass: UIImage.self)
}
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession) -> UIDropProposal {
    return UIDropProposal(operation: .copy)
}
//MARK:- drag item
func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession) -> [UIDragItem] {
    let touchedPoint = session.location(in: self.view)
    if let touchedImageVIew = self.view.hitTest(touchedPoint, with: nil) as? UIImageView{
        let touchedImage = touchedImageVIew.image
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: touchedImage!)
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        dragItem.localObject = touchedImageVIew
        return [dragItem]
    }
    return []
}

func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, willAnimateLiftWith animator: UIDragAnimating, session: UIDragSession) {
    session.items.forEach({ dragItem in
        if let touchedImageView = dragItem.localObject as? UIView{
            touchedImageView.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    })
}

func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, item: UIDragItem, willAnimateCancelWith animator: UIDragAnimating) {
    self.view.addSubview(item.localObject as! UIView)
}
func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, previewForLifting item: UIDragItem, session: UIDragSession) -> UITargetedDragPreview? {
    return UITargetedDragPreview(view: item.localObject as! UIView)
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am looking to use UITableView drag and drop support here.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your cell by these `UITableView` delegates methods

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        YOUR_ARRAY.moveItem(at: sourceIndexPath.row, to: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I am looking to use iOS 11 drag and drop support.

Comment: Yes with this answer you can drag and drop of your cell

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with iPhone then you have to explicitly set the following property in your **ViewController**'s viewDidLoad

```
tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
```